What formal translation for Russell's "for all values of x, 'x is a man or a woman' either implies 'x is a man' or implies 'x is a woman'”?
In Principles of Mathematics (1903), Bertrand Russell asserts the following:

It is true that, for all values of x, “x is a man or a woman” either implies “x is a man” or implies “x is a woman”.

As is usual in Russell's philosophical discussions of logical questions, the discussion remains informal throughout. He doesn't offer any formal translation of his assertion.
On the face of it, he seems to mean this:

∀x(((Mx ∨ Wx) → Mx) ⊻ ((Mx ∨ Wx) → Wx))

Or perhaps:

∀x(((Mx ∨ Wx) → Mx) ∨ ((Mx ∨ Wx) → Wx))

Which is it?
Or maybe it is something else?
Did anyone ever published a systematic formal translation of Russell's many informally articulated logical claims?
Or are they supposed to be obvious?
Thank you for any scholarly reference.
(typo corrected)

The reading is: from "for all x, either Man(x) or Woman (x)" we cannot deduce "either for all x Man(x) or for all x Woman (x)", but we can deduce (in modern notation): either Man(a) or Woman(a), for an unspecified a".

Russell specifies that "English people are all either men or women" earlier in this section. So he does mean exclusive or, as in the first OP version, but it only works because  predicates M and W are mutually exclusive. For generic M, W, one has to use either ⊻ or ∨ throughout (as in the second version) to make it valid.

I don't think either translation is right, nor is any predicate logic formula, because he is making a meta-claim about meaning. He's saying that in a disjunction like Mx ∨ Wx, having the same variable on both sides of the disjunction, for any given value of the variable, one branch or the other of the disjunction is the true one. There isn't a value of x for which the disjunction is irreducible.

I agree. Russell's statement does not translate into predicate logic. Russell is making the point that "x is a man or a woman" can be understood as "x is a man or x is a woman". To say, "x is a man or a woman" makes sense in natural language, but elementary predicate logic does not allow us to compose the predicates man(x), woman(x) into a composite man-or-woman(x). Instead we write "x is a man or x is a woman", i.e. man(x) ∨ woman(x). The inclusive/exclusive reading of 'or' does not matter as long as we are consistent with it.

@Bumble Russell's statement does translate because the implication is not from "x is a man or a woman" to "x is a man or x is a woman". His second "or" is between two separate instances of "implies" instead, as in the OP. And the sentence right after has a contrasting single instance:"But it is false that "x is a man or woman" either implies "x is a man" or "x is a woman" for all values of x." In other words, ∀ does not distribute over disjunction. See Principles, § 13.

@Conifold Fair enough. In which case, Russell's wording is somewhat clumsy. It would be better to say, "x is a man or x is a woman", since 'or' cannot sit between predicate terms. Also, it would read better if he said 'any' instead of 'all'.

Colloquially, the language is clear as it stands; he is simply asserting that when only two states of a variable are available , the value must be one or the other. Admittedly he neglects defining the terms man and woman, and we now recognize that other values are possible.

@Bumble Agreed. His use of placement of "for all values" in a sentence to indicate its scope does not make for much clarity either. I had to reread his surrounding paragraph a few times to make sense of it.

Reading Russell's account of material and formal implication is painful. It would all be so much simpler and clearer if Russell knew some model theory and possessed the concept of an interpretation. But that didn't come until later. Russell seems to confuse an argument with a conditional, despite this distinction being as old as the stoics. No wonder Quine accused Russell of a use/mention error.

There is no need of exclusive or to formalize Russell's example. The second formalization above (typo corrected):

∀x(((Mx ∨ Wx) → Mx) ∨ ((Mx ∨ Wx) → Wx)),

is the corerct one.
Simple argument by cases: let a an object that is not a human being; the antecedents of both conditionals are False, and thus both conditionals are True.
Let a be a human being.
Then two sub-cases: (i) a is a man, in which case the first conditional is True, or (ii) a is a woman, in which case the second one is True.
Conclusion: in all possible cases the disjunction is True and thus the universal closure of the formula holds.
The full paragraph (page 12) is:

It is true that, for all values of x, “x is a man or a woman” either implies “x is a man” or implies “x is a woman”. But it is false that “x is a man or woman” either implies “x is a man” for all values of x, or implies “x is a woman” for all values of x. Thus the implication involved, which is always one of the two, is not formal, since it does not hold for all values of x, being not always the same one of the two.

The false example is: ∀x((Mx ∨ Wx) → Mx) ∨ ∀x ((Mx ∨ Wx) → Wx)).
Note on Russell's terminology: a formal implication is the universal closure of a conditional: see example "all men are mortal" (page 37: “x is a man implies x is a mortal for all values of x”). The formula discussed is not a formal implication because is the universal closure of a disjunction.

In a modern text, this would be saying that the formal statement ∀x(Mx ∨ Wx) can be stated multiple equivalent ways in a natural language. They only appear different because English allows us to drop the repeated “X is” in the sentence “X is a man or [X is] a woman,” with no change to the semantics whatsoever.
You don’t give the context of Russell’s remark, so I can’t tell you if he was making another point.

So basically we're talking about ∀x. (M∨W)x → (Mx∨Wx). Which is nonsensical in standard predicate logic but could easily be made rigorous by overloading the OR-operator extensionally, which would make this a tautology.

@leftaroundabout I don't think that's necessarily nonsensical as long as we consider MvW to be a proper predicate (NB: I've changed the '∨' into a 'v' so that it will be valid syntax for most formal languages). Now, that predicate will most likely be defined as something like Mz ∨ Wz, where z is just a different dummy variable than x, to give us at least a little room to debate whether it's a tautology or not.

@leftaroundabout I don’t think extending a formal logic with that notation for first-order propositions, and making it distributive, would break anything.

The context of that statement is relevant.
Russel is leading into a discussion of the distinction between propositions and propositional expressions containing what he calls a "real variable". To illustrate, he starts by presenting this formally provable statement of propositional logic:

If p, q, r are propositions, and p implies q or r, then p implies q or p implies r.

Symbolically, that's ...
(p ⇒ (q ∨ r)) ⇒ ((p ⇒ q) ∨ (p ⇒ r))
.... where it is to be understood that such a propositional formula assumes p, q, and r to be propositions.
He then proposes to take these specific p, q, and r: "x is a man or a woman", "x is a man", and "x is a woman".  The sentence you're asking about is an English rendering of the resulting p ⇒ (q ∨ r), which Russel thus suggests might be expressed formally as "x is a man or a woman" ⇒ ("x is a man" ∨ "x is a woman").  Seems uncontroversial, right?  Even to the extent that we're comfortable standing a universal quantifier in front?
Not so fast.  Russel then observes that notwithstanding the manifest truth of the propositional formula from which we started, it is not true that ("x is a man or a woman" ⇒ "x is a man") ∨ ("x is a man or a woman" ⇒ "x is a woman").  It follows that the the formal proposition in the previous paragraph must be false, thus the English "implies" in "x is a man or a woman either implies x is a man or x is a woman" is not to be taken as a formal implication in the propositional sense.  Indeed, none of the three statements about x is a formal proposition at all, being neither true nor false until we choose a particular value of x.  They are rather expressions conveying forms of propositions in terms of variable x.

Russell starts with a premise having an „or“ and ends with a conclusion having an “xor”.
Hence Russell uses implicitly, but correctly

M(x) or W( x) -> M(x) xor W(x)

because "not(M(x) and W(x))".

I disagree. The statement does not hinge on (nor focus on) a specific OR/XOR choice. Whatever your interpretation of his premise, the same interpretation holds for the conclusion. X is (M OR W) -> (X is M) OR (X is W) holds true, as does X is (M XOR W) -> (X is M) XOR (X is W). Sure, we can infer that based on the cultural norm at the time, Russel was highly likely to think of gender as inherently being a binary XOR, but that's not relevant for the logic itself, it works for both OR and XOR.


It is true that, for all values of x, “x is a man or a woman” either implies “x is a man” or implies “x is a woman”.

Your focus on it being an OR or an XOR is irrelevant. In either case, as long as you consistently apply it to both instances of "or" (see the bolded parts), Russel's statement holds true.
In logical terms, this one is not correct:
∀x(((Mx ∨ Wx) → Mx) ⊻ ((Mx ∨ Wx) → Wx))

But these ones can both be considered to be correct applications of what Russell was conveying:
∀x(((Mx ⊻ Wx) → Mx) ⊻ ((Mx ∨ Wx) → Wx))

∀x(((Mx ∨ Wx) → Mx) ∨ ((Mx ∨ Wx) → Wx))

Russel's focus isn't on the distinction between OR/XOR. The focus is on the ability to decompose a complex statement into two simpler ones.
Contextually, you can infer that Russel was thinking of gender as a binary selection of complementary options (based on his age and the cultural norm at the time, and also his lack of ever pointing out the overlap you would get with an OR but not an XOR), which suggests he was thinking of XOR. But it's simply not relevant, because OR works just as well.
